# Xtext DSL embedded editor in a dialog

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, xtext

I am new to xtext, and i have created a DSL using xtext and i have generated the artifacts, which has generated the editor which has many features like content assist and syntax coloring now the problem is i want to embed the editor inside a dialog.

For achieving this im using EmbeddedEditor, i am able to get the embedded editor and place it in the dialog, but the embedded editor is not displaying the contents of the file.

The file C:/Eclipse_Work/workspace/runtime_workspace/apa/ex.mydsl contains:

```
import com.ex.test;
entity{
 element a;
}
```

The code in the createcontrol() of dialog is :

```java
    IEditedResourceProvider resourceProvider=new IEditedResourceProvider() {
        
        @Override
        public XtextResource createResource() {
            try {

                Resource resource = resourceSet.createResource(URI.createURI("C:/Eclipse_Work/workspace/runtime_workspace/apa/ex.mydsl"));
                XtextResource resource2=(XtextResource)resource;
                
                return (XtextResource) resource;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    };
    
    MyDslActivator activator = MyDslActivator.getInstance();
    Injector injector = activator
            .getInjector(MyDslActivator.COM_APAMA_STUDIO_QUERY_EXT_MYDSL);
    
    @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
    EmbeddedEditorFactory factory = injector.getInstance(EmbeddedEditorFactory.class);
   EmbeddedEditor handle= factory.newEditor(resourceProvider).withParent(
            composite);
   
   EmbeddedEditorModelAccess partialEditor= handle.createPartialEditor();

   
   handle.getViewer().getControl().setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true, 2, 0));
```

When i run the project the dialog opens with a editor area but it is not displaying the code present in ex.mydsl, the editor is empty.

Please tell me how to show the code in the embedded editor

Comment: I am looking to create an xtext editor out of eclipse in java.. Did you find a solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the editor's initial contents as the `editablePart` parameter of [`createPartialEditor(String prefix, String editablePart, String suffix, boolean insertLineBreaks)`](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/javadoc/2.4/org/eclipse/xtext/ui/editor/embedded/EmbeddedEditor.html#createPartialEditor%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29). To obtain your `XtextResource`'s contents as text, [save](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.4.2/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/resource/Resource.html#save%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.util.Map%29) it to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then convert it to a string using `toString.`